# Meteor: how can I drop all Mongo collections and clear all data on startup?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor app which configures itself from a JSON API on startup.  In order to properly coordinate all the clients, it builds a couple Mongo collections and stores data in them which clients then subscribe too.  However, if the Meteor app is restarted, I would like it to wipe the database clean and re-configure itself from scratch.

How can I get Meteor to drop all data and start from a clean slate each time the server code is restarted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using `Meteor.startup` server-side ?

It allows you to register a callback that will get executed each time the server is (re)started.

Then you can use `MyCollection.remove({})` inside to wipe out everything.

The following piece of code clears every globally registered Meteor.Collection (ie using `MyCollection=new Meteor.Collection("collection-name")`) on every fresh start :

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    var globalObject=Meteor.isClient?window:global;
    for(var property in globalObject){
        var object=globalObject[property];
        if(object instanceof Meteor.Collection){
            object.remove({});
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who come here in 2017, there is also the option to use the `meteor reset` command from the meteor cli.

http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorreset

> **meteor reset**
>
> Reset the current project to a fresh state. Removes the local mongo
>   database.
>
> This deletes your data! Make sure you do not have any information you
>   care about in your local mongo database by running meteor mongo. From
>   the mongo shell, use show collections and db.collection.find() to
>   inspect your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you would actually like to drop every collection instead of just removing the objects, you could instead do:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    var globalObject=Meteor.isClient?window:global;
    for(var property in globalObject){
        var object=globalObject[property];
        if(object instanceof Meteor.Collection){
            object.rawCollection().drop();
        }
    }
});
```

This would ensure any collections that have been removed from code get dropped.